# Getting List of Collections in Firebase that was added programmatically

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have a class that have the codes below:

```
final fi = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
//FR - Firestore Reference

String getCollectionName(QuizPaperModel quizPaper) {
  switch (quizPaper.category) {
// did some logic here
  }
}

newQuizPaperFR(QuizPaperModel quizPaper) {
  return fi
      .collection("quizpapers")
      .doc(getCollectionName(quizPaper))
      .collection("papers");
}
```

Now I want to use the `newQuizPaperFR()` in different parts of my codes.

For eg, in QuizController class, I used it like this:

```
void loadData(QuizPaperModel quizPaper) async {
    quizPaperModel = quizPaper;

    loadingStatus.value = LoadingStatus.loading;

    try {
      final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> questionQuery =
          await newQuizPaperFR(quizPaper)
              .doc(quizPaper.id)
              .collection("questions")
              .get();
// other logic
}
```

The above **DID NOT** have an issue because, in the same class, I created:

```
late QuizPaperModel quizPaperModel;
```

Then, in `onReady()`, I did this:

```
final quizPaper = Get.arguments as QuizPaperModel; 
// argument is passed when navigating to the page using the controller.
```

So everything **works fine**.

**My issue arises** when I tried using the `newQuizPaperFR` method in another class, `QuizPaperController`.

Relevant codes (to this question) in the class are:

```
    class QuizPaperController extends GetxController {
      @override
      void onReady() {
final quizPaperModel = Get.argument as QuizPaperModel; // causes app crash when launched 
        getAllPapers(quizPaperModel);
        super.onReady();
      }

late QuizPaperModel quizPaperModel;
    
final loadingStatus = LoadingStatus.loading.obs;
  final allPapers = <QuizPaperModel>[].obs;
  final prosePapers = <QuizPaperModel>[].obs;
  final dramasPapers = <QuizPaperModel>[].obs;
  final novelsPapers = <QuizPaperModel>[].obs;
  final africanPoetriesPapers = <QuizPaperModel>[].obs;
  final nonAfricanPoetriesPapers = <QuizPaperModel>[].obs;
    
 Future<void> getAllPapers(QuizPaperModel quizPaper) async {


    loadingStatus.value = LoadingStatus.loading;

quizPaperModel = quizPaper;
    try {
      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> data = await newQuizPaperFR(quizPaper)
          .get(); 

      final paperList =
          data.docs.map((paper) => QuizPaperModel.fromSnapshot(paper)).toList();

      for (var paper in paperList) {
        final imageUrl =
            await Get.find<FirebaseStorageService>().getImage(paper.imageName);
        paper.imageUrl = imageUrl;

        final pdfUrl = await Get.find<FirebaseStorageService>()
            .getPdfUrl(paper.completePdfName);

        paper.completePdfUrl = pdfUrl;

        final summaryPdfUrl = await Get.find<FirebaseStorageService>()
            .getPdfUrl(paper.summaryPdfName);

        paper.summaryPdfUrl = summaryPdfUrl;

        // Add paper to the appropriate category list
        switch (paper.category) {
          case "prose":
            prosePapers.add(paper);
            break;
          case "dramas":
            dramasPapers.add(paper);
            break;
          case "novels":
            novelsPapers.add(paper);
            break;
          case "african-poetries":
            africanPoetriesPapers.add(paper);
            break;
          case "non-african-poetries":
            nonAfricanPoetriesPapers.add(paper);
            break;
          default:
            throw Exception(
                "Invalid category for quiz paper: ${paper.category}");
        }
        loadingStatus.value = LoadingStatus.completed;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      loadingStatus.value = LoadingStatus.error;
      AppLogger.e(e);
    }
  }
```

As expected from the code above, on app launch, the app **crashes**, with the exception

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'QuizPaperModel' in type cast
```

This obviously happens because **no argument** was passed to the `MyHomeScreen()` using the QuizPaperController.

The `MyHomeScreen()` can only be seen when a user **logs into the app** through `LogInScreen()`

For more context,

This is my `SignIn()` method (in **AuthController**)

```
 Future<void> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

    try {
//did logic

        navigateToHomeScreen();
      }
    } on Exception catch (error) {
      AppLogger.e(error);
    }
  }
```

This is my `navigateToHomeScreen()` (in **AuthController**)

```
void navigateToHomeScreen() {
    Get.offAllNamed(
      MyHomeScreen.routeName,
    );
  }
```

I tried making the `navigateToHomeScreen()` take the `QuizPaperModel quizModel` argument. Like this:

```
void navigateToHomeScreen({required QuizPaperModel quizPaperModel}) {
    final category = quizPaperModel.category;
    Get.offAllNamed(
      MyHomeScreen.routeName,
      arguments: category,
    );
  }
```

Expectedly, this leads to another error, insisting I specify the quizModel whenever the `navigateToHomeScreen()` method is called.

This is what my `QuizPaperModel` looks like:

```
class QuizPaperModel {
  QuizPaperModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.completePdfUrl,
    this.summaryPdfUrl,
    required this.description,
    required this.timeInSeconds,
    required this.questions,
    required this.questionCount,
    required this.imageName,
    required this.completePdfName,
    required this.summaryPdfName,
    required this.category, // new property
  });

  QuizPaperModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json["id"],
        title = json["title"] as String,
        imageName = json["imageName"] as String,
        completePdfName = json["completePdfName"] as String,
        summaryPdfName = json["summaryPdfName"] as String,
        completePdfUrl = json["completePdfUrl"] as String?,
        summaryPdfUrl = json["summaryPdfUrl"] as String?,
        imageUrl = json["image_url"] as String?,
        description = json["description"] as String,
        timeInSeconds = json["timeInSeconds"] as int,
        category = json["category"] as String, // initialize category property
        questionCount = 0,

        // will be updated in PaperDataUploaded
        questions = json["questions"] == null
            ? []
            : (json["questions"] as List)
                .map((e) => QuizQuestion.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
                .toList();
  // subCollection = json["subCollection"]
  //     as String; // initialize the subCollection property

  QuizPaperModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : id = snapshot.id,
        title = snapshot["title"],
        imageUrl = snapshot["image_url"],
        completePdfUrl = snapshot["completePdfUrl"],
        summaryPdfUrl = snapshot["summaryPdfUrl"],
        imageName = snapshot["imageName"],
        completePdfName = snapshot["completePdfName"],
        summaryPdfName = snapshot["summaryPdfName"],
        description = snapshot["description"],
        timeInSeconds = snapshot["timeInSeconds"],
        category = snapshot["category"], //initialize category property
        questionCount = snapshot["questions_count"] as int,
        questions = [];
  // subCollection =
  //     snapshot["subCollection"]; // initialize the subCollection property

  factory QuizPaperModel.fromString(String jsonString) =>
      QuizPaperModel.fromJson(json.decode(jsonString));

  final String description;
  final String id;
  String? completePdfUrl;
  String? summaryPdfUrl;
  String? imageUrl;
  final int questionCount;
  List<QuizQuestion>? questions;
  final int timeInSeconds;
  final String title;
  final String imageName;
  String completePdfName;
  String summaryPdfName;
  String category; // new property
  //String subCollection; // new property

  String timeInMinutes() => "${(timeInSeconds / 60).ceil()} mins";

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "imageName": imageName,
        "completePdfName": completePdfName,
        "summaryPdfName": summaryPdfName,
        "completePdfUrl": completePdfUrl,
        "summaryPdfUrl": summaryPdfUrl,
        "image_url": imageUrl,
        "description": description,
        "timeInSeconds": timeInSeconds,
        "category": category, // new property
        //"subCollection": subCollection,
      };
}
```

I have tried other things like making **parameters** in `QuizPaperModel` **nullable** so that I can **instantiate it in another file** without the need to specify the parameters, but this still gives me another error since the model is basically working with firebase...

**My question:**

1. Is there a workaround for this issue,
2. Can I modify my `newQuizPaperFR()` method and still achieve the same result, i.e get the papers in the `firebase database`?
3. What am I missing?